# How to optimize this mysql Query? on nginx and fastcgi

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, fastcgi, redbean

i have a web app built on code igniter framework on the top of nginx , fastcgi and mysql

i have a payout table . table structure is [here](http://pastebin.com/BYspUUJT).

in this table , country names , perminutecost vs are stored and nearly 56,373 records on it.

---

in main page , there is a form that requests user to type his cellphone number to retrieve perminute cost.Btw i am using auto-complete feature as user types in

here is my backend code:

$str holds user input(cellphone number)

> $ret = true;
>               $count = 3;

```
        while($ret){
            $sub = substr($str,0,$count); //9053
            $ret = R::getAll("SELECT Destination,PerMinuteCost FROM `payout` WHERE `Prefix` REGEXP '^$sub(.)*$' LIMIT 0 , 30");
            $count++;
        }

        $sub = substr($str,0,$count-2);

        $ret =  R::getAll("SELECT Destination,PerMinuteCost FROM `payout` WHERE `Prefix` REGEXP '^$sub(.)*$' LIMIT 0 , 30");

        return $ret[0];
```

this code lets me get perminutecost from a cellphone number.(the table holds just prefixes not all the cell phone numbers)

i did some modifications on nginx and fastcgi to extend timeout limits

but when too much people use the service at the same time , mysqld cpu usage is getting over 100% ,

how could i improve this algorithm ?

thanks.

Comment: Is the REGEX for autocomplete?  Because I would remove that immediately.

Comment: :) this is my fast-production code.Now I am searching on optimization.

Comment: Could you post in a sample of what the user would enter? Are you suggesting they would type '0' then '01' then '012'?

Comment: user types 905303818191 for example.they type their phone number to get payoutrate.

Comment: I am unable to edit your post without changing your title, because a million posts already exist with the title "How to optimize this mysql query ?". That's a sign that your title is broken. Please fix it! Also, are a few capital letters too much to ask for...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think just a LIKE '$sub%' would be faster than regex and it might be better for your db if they are not autocompleting until 3 numbers.

Post some example SQL output if you put "EXPLAIN" at the beginning of the sql outside of this script.

Comment: Also adding some sort of caching for last entered values for the form might make faster for most common searches

Comment: What's nginx got to do with MySQL?

Comment: MySQL would be able to use an index when using LIKE for a prefix search. Application level caching brings cache invalidation issues and should be avoided unless there is evidence of a significant benefit.

Answer (score 3):

You could create another table that stores prefixes for your prefixes. For example, if an entry in your payout table has prefix = 12345, your prefixTable will have 5 associated rows: 1, 12, 123, 1234, and 12345. Each entry will be linked to the original record by a foreign key. To search, you would find an exact match in prefixTable and then join back to your payout table to get the payout information.

This will of course use up more space on the server but should offer you a significant speed boost.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the `Prefix` column from `TEXT` to a `VARCHAR` column with the minimum required length, and add an index on the `Prefix` column.

Then, instead of using a regular expression, use `LIKE` with the `%` wildcard:

```
SELECT Destination, PerMinuteCost
FROM `payout` WHERE `Prefix` LIKE '$sub%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: if they are all numbers of the same length (or similar) you might just want an int column over a varchar as all varchar rows end up being stored as the data length of the longest entry. plus you would not want to enter a Character in by mistake, unless you need spaces?

Comment: @tristanbailey, VARCHAR values do not get stored as the data length of the longest entry. That's not even true for indexes. VARCHAR columns use the first one to two bytes to store the length of the value for each row. The remainder is actually variable length, matching the value.